# Passenger: RailsBaseURI case sensitive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I used [Passenger](http://modrails.com/) to deploy a RoR app to a sub URI on my domain. The problem I'm facing is that the sub URI seems to be case sensitive. Navigating to http://mydomain.com/RailsApp resolves fine. However, if I go to http://mydomain.com/railsapp, http://mydomain.com/railsApp, or any other variation, I get a 404 error. How can these requests using different casings get resolved correctly?

Here is my Apache configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /www/mydomain/public

  <Directory "/www/mydomain/public">
      RailsEnv "production"
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  RailsBaseURI /RailsApp
  <Directory "/www/RailsApp/public">
      RailsEnv "development"
      Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: URLs are by definition case-sensitive, so before you ask this question be sure that you have a good reason for making them case-insensitive. The easiest thing to do will be to rename the folder to its lowercase version on the server, but that will just make it work as lowercase, it won't make it case-insensitive

Comment: @Gareth: The reason is so users can still navigate to the URL regardless of their letter casing. For example, going to http://stackoverflow.com/Questions or http://stackoverflow.com/QuEsTiOnS still points to http://stackoverflow.com/questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [ba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68035/ba) for pointing me in the right direction.

I did some research and found the [mod_speling](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_speling.html) module. This not only makes the URL case-insensitive but also checks for spelling errors.

To enable mod_speling:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/a2enmod speling

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

To use mod_speling, include the directive `CheckSpelling on` in your virtual host section:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    CheckSpelling on

    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using `mod_rewrite` and matching it case insensitive there.

Some links to get you started :)
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/rewriteguide.html